# Request [/.../_search] contains unrecognized parameters: [_], [callback] AJAX and elasticsearch 5.x

Tags: javascript, ajax, elasticsearch

I have part AJAX code, but it returns status 400 Bad Request

```
 {
  "error" : {
 "root_cause" : [
   {
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "request [/.../_search] contains unrecognized parameters: [_], [callback]
```

My code is blow:

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url:url/_search?pretty=true',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify(query)
        }).done(function(xhr) {
            alert("Success");
        }).fail(function(xhr) {
                           alert(xhr.hits.hits);
        })
```

I have enabled Cross in elasticsearch.yml file with http.cors.enabled: true. Need some help pls

Answer (score 0):

Those parameters are being added because you have told jQuery to expect a JSONP response. Consequently it is making a JSONP request (with `<script>` tags instead of `XMLHttpRequest`) and telling the server what callback function name to use.

As a side-effect this forces the request to be GET and prevents headers (such as `content-type`) being modified.

Don't tell jQuery to use JSONP unless the API requires that you do (JSONP is a dirty hack that has been superceeded by CORS so you should only have to use it with legacy APIs now).